# Azure DevOps Role based menu item

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

Currently I have build an Azure DevOps extension with a menu item who is visible for everyone. This was not a problem, but now we want to hide some of the pages for specific user groups.

I can only find limited information about setting up custom menu items and I didn't find any solution how to make the menu item role or team based.

Below you can see my current extension file. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

```
{
    // ...
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "xxx-hub-group",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub-group",
            "description": "XXX",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-web.project-hub-groups-collection"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "XXX",
                "icon": "img/xxx.png"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "sub-xxx",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "description": "sub-xxx",
            "targets": [
                ".xxx-hub-group"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "sub-xxx",
                "title": "sub-xxx",
                "icon": "img/sub-xxx.png",
                "uri": "pages/sub-xxx.html",
                "supportedScopes": [
                    "project_team"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```